# Brackets [ ] around string with grep and ps - ef

Tags: bash, grep, brackets, ps

I am trying to get the time of the process start. 
Usually I use the brackets on the first letter of the process that I am running. 
It takes away the self reporting "grep" in the ps output.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
restarTXG="sendevent -E FORCE_STARTJOB -J CASPERRT_CD_TXG_DR_STR_PS"
bounceTXG="sendevent -E FORCE_STARTJOB -J CASPERRT_CD_TXG_DR_STP_PS; sleep 10 ; sendevent -E FORCE_STARTJOB -J CASPERRT_CD_TXG_DR_STR_PS"
timeofTXG=$(ps -ef | grep [t]xg | awk '{print $5}' )

if [ -n "$timeofTXG" ] ; then
    printf "%s\n" "The TXG_DR is ON as of $timeofTXG"
else
    printf "%s\n" "'The TXG_DR is OFF"
fi
```

18:40 is the time I run the check script.  17:44 is the time the process started.

```
++ ps -ef
++ grep '[t]xg'
++ awk '{print $5}'
+ timeofTXG='17:44
18:40
18:40'
+ '[' -n '17:44
18:40
18:40' ']'
+ printf '%s\n' 'The TXG_DR is ON as of 17:44
18:40
18:40'
The TXG_DR is ON as of 17:44
18:40
18:40
```

I don't really know how the square brackets work.   When I run the ps from the command line, the [] brackets do work -- ps -ef | grep [t]xg | awk '{print $5}'
however in the context of the bash script, they are not working, they are giving me the time of the self reporting grep. 
How do the brackets work?  Why do they work on the command line and not in the script?   How do I get rid of the self revealing grep in bash script ?

Comment: You need quotes to prevent `[t]xg` from being replaced with `txg` by the shell if there's any file by that name in the current directory. That is to say, the code should be `'[t]xg'`.

Comment: ...or, better, don't grep `ps` at all, but use a special-purpose tool such as `pgrep` instead.

Comment: Or, even better than that, don't even *look* at the process table but write your software to use advisory locking or your OS-provided process supervision system (systemd, runit, daemontools, upstart, launchd, whatever it may be).

Comment: The square brackets are [Grep Regex](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr3.txt). You should be wary using a tool that you don't really understand. Whenever you see something being done "just because it works," you should usually try to find out why it works, because as soon as the situation changes just a little bit, it's hard to adapt what you don't know how it works to your new situation.

Comment: @Davy Yes - I am putting in a concerted effort to understand the tools.

Comment: @Charles - protecting the grep command with bullet quotes does not seem to protect it from the shell. it still gives the three times.  I still don't understand why it works on command line, and why does not work when inserted into a bash script.

Comment: The point of the quotes is to prevent the `grep` itself from being matched -- grepping for `[t]xg` doesn't match `grep '[t]xg'`, but does match `txg` itself. Consequently, the quotes don't help if you actually *have* three processes that contain `txg` -- which can happen if the program you're running has subshells or subprocesses, for example.

Comment: Indeed, the fact that your `grep` results all have the same time (when your `txg` process was started, presumably) instead of one of them having the time of the `grep` itself tells us that the problem you're having *isn't* the one that the `[t]xg` practice is intended to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `awk` already you don't need `grep`, do something like this (which I guess is your intention):

```
ps -ef | awk '$8 ~ /txg/ {print $5}'
```

Comment: I'm not at all convinced that the output of `ps -ef` is sufficiently well-defined as to provide a guarantee that the column you want (with the executable name) will be `$8` across all pertinent platforms. Yes, `-f` is guaranteed by POSIX to provide a "full listing", which guarantees a specific set of fields, but the content of each field -- and thus whether `awk` will parse it as one field or more than one -- is implementation defined.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy very true, however, the intention was to show that if you have `awk` in your pipe you probably don't need `grep` and it's for sure more restricted than grepping the whole line.